# How to fix a floating menu in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I'm launching a website on Friday and having an issue with the top menu which is floating - rather than fixed at the top - for reasons beyond me.

Unfortunately, You can see a bit of the header photo in between the top of the menu and the top of the page on a desktop.

Here's the URL and I've included an image below: http://cricketyorks.staging.wpengine.com

**Any code suggestions you have that I can add to custom css in the back-end of Wordpress to fix this would be really appreciated.**

It must be something I've tweaked in the past because the theme (Arcade) has a fixed top menu normally. Thanks - and over to you!

[image: Homepage screenshot]

Comment: I am checking the link and don't see any issue with your top menu

Comment: There is an style `position: absolute` added to `nav#site-navigation`.
You need to either remove it if possible or overwrite it in your css to `position: fixed`. I see it is already set to `position: fixed` in the theme css file but is being overwritten by the inline style

Comment: @Bart - thanks for the feedback and clear explanation - I don't know why it's being overwritten from position:fixed. If I was to try a fix using custom css, what would the code be I could try? Not knowing css, I'm afraid I wouldn't know where to start...

Comment: @DragutescuAlexandru - that's odd because, as the screenshot shows, it's definitely hanging when viewed in Firefox on a Mac. Different devices and browsers perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this css for your nav

```
nav#site-navigation {
    position: absolute;
}
```

With `position:absolute` you can set a position of a element anywhere on the page but cannot fixed the position for fixing the position you need to change this css to `position:fixed` like this

```
nav#site-navigation {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code suggestion that fixed the problem. What I had failed to notice was that (also in the custom css from a previous tweak) the same code as above but position: absolute. Can't believe I missed it though I wouldn't have known to change it to 'fixed' - but that was why it wasn't working. This is why Stack Overflow is awesome, quick and accurate help when needed!